# Integrating legendre polymial in terms of cosx

Tags: calculus, integration, legendre-polynomials

I was solving a problem in physics and got stuck at this integral:

$$\int_0^\pi P_l(\cos\theta)\sin(\theta)\text{d}\theta$$

How can I compute this integral in terms of $l$? I can find the integral for a given $l$ like 2 by substituting $P_2(\cos\theta)$. And In general, how can I integrate 
$$\int_0^\pi f(\theta) P_l(\cos\theta)\sin(\theta)\text{d}\theta$$

Answer (score 2):

First step: Make a change of variables to $x=cos(\theta)$. Then you will get $\int_{-1}^{1} P_l(x) dx$

Step two: Think of the the integral as $\int_{-1}^1 P_l P_0 dx$. Then there are formulas (sort've like orthogonality relations) which tell you how to integrate the product of two Legendre polynomials. [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LegendrePolynomial.html). At the link it also gives formulas for integrating the product of two legendre polynomials when multiplied by $x$ or $x^2$. I am not sure how to do it for a general function but I suspect that may suffice if you are doing quantum mechanics.

Answer (score 1):

For the first integral, make a simple substitution:
$$x = \cos \theta$$
$$dx = -\sin \theta d \theta $$
$$\theta = \{0, \pi \} \implies x = \{1, -1\}$$

and rewrite the integral as:

$$
\int_{-1}^1 P_l(x) dx
$$

If we use the property that the Legendre polynomials are orthogonal, with
$$ \int_{-1}^1 P_l(x) P_m(x) = \frac{2}{2 m + 1} \delta_{m l}
$$
as well as
$$ P_0(x) = 1$$

Then we find that the first integral is $0$ for all choices of $l$ except $l=0$, for which the value is $2$. That is,
$$
\int_0^\pi P_l(\cos \theta) \sin \theta d \theta = 2 \delta_{l 0}.
$$

For the second integral, make the same substitution to get
$$
\int_0^\pi f(\theta) P_l(\cos \theta) \sin \theta d \theta =\int_{-1}^1 f(\cos^{-1}(x)) P_l(x) dx.
$$

That's pretty much as general as you can get, without knowing the form of $f$.